# computing likelihood of pixel belonging to an object using gradient orientation

Tags: c++, image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am working on object estimation on a image, that is tracking. Basically, I use gradient orientation as a feature descriptor of each pixel. I compute the gradient of each pixel and bin the orientation into 9-bin histogram therefore each pixel in the image is represented by a 9-dimension vector.

At initialization step a static foreground and background models are constructed as above.

Now the problem I have is that the background and the foreground are composed of many pixels (say k), therefore I will k x 9 dimension histograms for each pixels. How can I compute the likelihood of each pixel such that I can determine if it belongs to the foreground or background.

If the background and foreground models are constructed using a single histogram than it I can use something like [compareHist in opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=comparehist#comparehist). However the tracking result is very poor so I want to work at the pixel level. I cannot think of an appropriate method to compute probabilities for the method I stated above.

Is there any efficient way to do this? One way is to do One vs All (in the model) comparison but this is too exhaustive search approach and is computationally expensive.

Comment: Dod you read about HOG detector ? It looks like you trying to do.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov actually I am not doing Block Normalization however just computing Gradient orientations on Neighboring Cells that is 3 x 3 pixels wide. Therefore I need to compute the likelihood.